# is it possible to detect IMAP protocol version?

Tags: node.js, imap

I am using Nodejs to establish IMAP IDLE connection for email client. Is there any possibility to detect IMAP protocol version when it establish connection.

Comment: Who is the client, who is the server? What is the role of Node.js?

Comment: I am having own client Program. Node.js will be the intermediate between my client Program and IMAP server. let here, i am going to use Gmail IMAP connection. but it is not specific to gmail always. it may be any mail server. so when i am connecting with particular mail server through Nodejs, i want to get connected IMAP server protocol version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All IMAP servers today run the same version, 4rev1. Versions 1, 2, 3 and 4 are long gone.

Further, all servers today support one or more extensions. The CAPABILITY command returns the list of extensions. For gmail:

```
openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993 -crlf

a capability
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
a OK Thats all she wrote! j14mb28178795bkd
```

So gmail supports IDLE and about a dozen more extensions.

Answer (score 4):

IMAP uses the [CAPABILITY](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-7.2.1) command to request information about the server capabilities. This is  more useful than a version number as it allows a client to check for the specific extensions to the IMAP basic protocol that it might require.